# Firebase email verification not sending

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implemented the sending of a confirmation email in a react app after filling out a sign up form, and tried to test locally using my own email, but I'm not receiving any emails, nor is the console logging my message, but it's still writing the data to the database, and I can see myself as a user in the authentication tab in my firebase console

**When a user submits the form:**

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase.auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.emailValue, this.state.passValue) 
    .then(() => {
        this.setState({
            showErrorMessage: false
        })
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        writeUserData(user.uid, this.state.name, this.state.emailValue)
        user.sendEmailVerification().then(() => {
            console.log("verification email sent")
        }).catch((error)=>console.error(error))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({
            error: error,
            showErrorMessage: true,
        })
        console.error(error)
    })
}
```

**When the form component mounts:**

```
componentWillMount() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                window.location = "thank-you"
            } 
        })
    }
```

I get this error in the console when I submit the form: `{code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}`

What am I doing wrong? I am following all the firebase documentation

Comment: Are you using Cordova? Could it be related to this bug; https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/581

Comment: Can you inspect your the network tab in the browser console and report the errors?